# Create a multi-level dynamic navigator

Tags: navigation, xpages

I want to create a two level Navigator where the top level is simply get.columnValues[0] of a categorized view. These values would not be linked to anything. I think I can do that with a a     xe:repeatTreeNode and feed it the columnValues from the view, but the I need to create a series of LeafNodes (one for each document under that category.

I could do this pretty easily with a repeatControl type of layout, but as I'm using the xe:navigator control in other places I would really like this to look the same. I have search to see if there is a code snippet that might get me to this but could not find anything.

Comment: Looked at several other solutions but then decided just to build a repeat control that looks remarkably like the Navigator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a beanTreeNode as the treeNode for your navigator.

See Jesse Gallagher's blog post "[Basic Org Charts With xe:navigator and xe:beanTreeNode](http://frostillic.us/f.nsf/posts/1FA5A6B665F0210E85257A33004257B2)" on this subject.

Comment: Thanks that will probably do the job with a little redefinition.